# Python time conversion to other format

Tags: python

I need to convert date string "2014-12-17 08:00:00.23" to string "08:00:00" in python. I looked at the datetime.strptime but still can't find a way for this. eg:

> 2014-12-17 08:00:00.23 to 08:00:00

what will be the pattern for the above time format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First parse it using `strptime`, then format the datetime object using `strftime`.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
import datetime
t = '2014-12-17 08:00:00.23'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
=> 08:00:00
```

Comment: as it contain a lot of file inside the text file so i need to find out the pattern. cn you help me to get the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If your time string is of fixed width, you can simply get the sub-string from the original time string:

```
In [90]: ts = '2014-12-17 08:00:00.23'

In [91]: ts[-11:-3]
Out[91]: '08:00:00'
```

If you want to get a datetime object, use `datetime` or `dateutil` module instead:

```
In [99]: from dateutil import parser
    ...: dt = parser.parse(ts)
    ...: dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
Out[99]: '08:00:00'
```

Comment: as it contain a lot of file inside the text file so i need to find out the pattern. cn you help me to get the pattern.